# What is wrong with my body-click event?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have that text field:

```
<input type='text' id='title' name='title'>
<div id='error' class='error'></div>
```

When user clicks out of the text field and there is a validation problem, the div "error" appears.

What I want to do is to hide that little div when user clicks anywhere in the body. 
I tried e.stopPropagation in the body click event but didn't work.

The div never appears because when I blur out of the textfield, it's considered a body click

Please let me know if you have any idea. Regards

EDIT:
I have updated the code. The code inside the body click event is supposed to hide the "error" div when anything but the text field is clicked, but can't get it to work.

```
$('body').click(function(event){
        if ($(event.target).closest('#title').get(0) == null ) { 
            $("#error").hide(); 
            }});

// Validation
$('#title').blur(function(){
    var titleinput=$('#title').val();
    if (titleinput.length <30 || titleinput.length >50){
        $('#error').text('Your title must be between 30 and 50 characters').show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: little edit: made a little mistake with the name of the error div. Problem is still the same.

Comment: "Anywhere in the body" is the entire clickable webpage. Including the `<input>`. There is nowhere in the page for the user to click that _is not_ the `<body>`. Change your requirements.

Comment: Your body click handler has not been properly closed, but I'm guessing that's a typo?

Comment: Hi, yes it is. Thanks for your responses. I am editing the post right now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, since `blur` and `click` are different events, you can't use `stopPropagation`.  The only way I can think to do this is to fake it.  You can ignore the first click that happens within a fraction of a second of the `blur` event.

http://jsfiddle.net/LeNDp/1

```
var ignoreClicks = false;
var timer;

$("body").click(function() {
    if(!ignoreClicks){
        $("#msg").fadeOut();
    }else{
        if(timer) clearTimeout(timer);
        ignoreClicks = false;        
    }
});

$("input").blur(function(e) {
    ignoreClicks = true;      
    $("#msg").stop(true,true).show();

    if(timer) clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(function(){ignoreClicks=false;}, 250);
});​
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks a lot for your message. That did it for me. Regards

Comment: How do you know that `blur` will fire before `click`? Is that in the docs for jQuery?

Comment: @CrazyJugglerDrummer I'm actually not sure if that is or isn't guarenteed.  In my experience I think this is the case.  It wouldn't be in the jQuery docs, it may be browser dependent.